# Speeding up function that compares strings

Tags: string, performance, scala

I have a function that takes two strings, s and obj. It checks if string obj can be formed from string s by removing 1 char. Implemention works okay but if becomes awfully slow when strings are larger. I was trying to figure out a way to make this piece of code work much faster. Could anyone figure out an implemention?

```
  def check_extra_char(s: String, obj: String): Boolean = {
    if(s.length != obj.length+1) return false                         // Automatically false if obj is not one char smaller than s
    for (i <- 0 until s.length)
      if (s.take(i) + s.substring(1+i) == obj) return true
    return false  
  }
```

Comment: *// Automatically false if obj is not one char smaller than s* But you're checking that it's *larger* by one character. Any reason you're not using `contains`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov no, his cond is okay. If `s.length` is *n* and `obj.length` is *n -1* as OP wants it to be than *+1* makes a correct condition.

Comment: @sebszyller But he's checking `!=` between the two. If `obj.length` was one char shorter, then `obj.length + 1` would yield true for `==`, wouldn't it? I mean, if `obj` is one char smaller then `s.length == obj.length + 1`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes, you are correct. The OP does it the other way round, he wants to *exit if they are of different size* rather than *continue if they are of the same size* which is weird, imo, but to each his own, I guess.

Comment: s can only be same as obj if and only if obj has one less char as s has 1 extra char. If obj had any other amount of chars statement would instantly be false

Comment: Observe: if we find the first position that the two strings differ, then if it can be done by removing that character, the rest of the strings after that have to be the same. This means you need only one `substring`

Comment: I did some profiling and it turns out pamu's answer is the fastest due to it's explicitness, followed by mine and Sarvesh's (one was faster than the other depending on the run) and followed by Duzzz's (that was painfully slow).

Answer (score 2):

Keep comparing characters of two strings one by one when mismatch happens skip the mismatch char and keep count of mismatches. If more than 1 mismatch happens check returns false. In the worst case time complexity of the check is O(n).

```
  def check(a: String, b: String): Boolean = {
   val smallerStr = if (a.length < b.length) a else b
   val largerStr = if (a.length > b.length) a else b

  if (largerStr.length - smallerStr.length > 1) false
  else {
    def countMismatches(aIndex: Int, bIndex: Int, mismatchCount: Int): Int = {

      if (bIndex < largerStr.length && aIndex < smallerStr.length) {

        if (smallerStr(aIndex) != largerStr(bIndex)) {
          if (mismatchCount > 1) mismatchCount
          else countMismatches(aIndex, bIndex + 1, mismatchCount + 1)
        }
        else countMismatches(aIndex + 1, bIndex + 1, mismatchCount)

      } else mismatchCount
    }

    countMismatches(0, 0, 0) <= 1
  }
}
```

**REPL**

```
res12: Boolean = true
@ check("zapple", "apple")
res13: Boolean = true
@ check("apple", "apzple")
res14: Boolean = true
@ check("apple", "apzzple")
res15: Boolean = false
@ check("apple", "applez")
res16: Boolean = true
@ check("apple", "applzz")
res17: Boolean = false
```

Comment: Well... I did that when it had mistakes... now it seems that I can not remove my down-vote for some time. I will once stackoverflow allows me to.

Comment: Upvoted. So... it seems that you can not remove a downvote. You can only convert it to an upvote. ThoughI do not want to upvote it, I do not want to downvote it either. My issue with this code - too much Java-like.

Comment: @pamu the code does not work unless you swap `a` with `b`.

Comment: @sebszyller ... cool .. edited the answer .. now this works irrespective of order

Answer (score 1):

You can speed it up by removing extra `s.take(i) + s.substring(i+1)`. You can go through s and compare index to its counterpart in obj. When you notice the difference, you use your `s.take(i) + s.substring(i+1)`.

```
  def check_extra_char(s: String, obj: String): Boolean = {
    if(s.length != obj.length+1) return false                         // Automatically false if obj is not one char smaller than s
    if(s.dropRight(1) == obj) return true    // so we don't go outOfIndex later
    for (i <- 0 until s.length)
      if (s(i) != obj(i)){
        if (s.take(i) + s.substring(1+i) == obj) return true else return false
    return false  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is `s.take(i) + s.substring(1+i) == obj` part. Both `String.take(i: Int)` and `String.substring(start: Int, end: Int)` have `O(n)` time-complexity.

There are numerous ways to avoid that and I am providing one of them in idiomatic scala with tail-recursion,

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def checkExtraChar(source: String, target: String): Boolean = {
  val sourceLength = source.length
  val targetLength = target.length

  // Assumption :: source.length == target.length + 1
  @tailrec
  def _check(srcIndex: Int, tgtIndex: Int, mismatchFound: Boolean): Boolean = srcIndex match {
    case index if index == (sourceLength - 1) && !mismatchFound => true
    case index if index == (sourceLength - 1) => source(srcIndex) == target(tgtIndex)
    case _ => (source(srcIndex) == target(tgtIndex), mismatchFound) match {
      case (true, _) => _check(srcIndex + 1, tgtIndex + 1, mismatchFound)
      case (false, false) => _check(srcIndex + 1, tgtIndex, true)
      case (false, true) => false
    }
  }

  (sourceLength == targetLength + 1) match {
    case false => false
    case true => _check(0, 0, false)
  }

}

checkExtraChar("qwerty", "werty") // true
checkExtraChar("wqerty", "werty") // true

checkExtraChar("qqwerty", "werty") // false
```

Comment: Your solution is quite neat ... but it assumes order of input which is not good. it fails for this input `checkExtraChar("applez", "apple")`

Comment: why should the order matter ?

Comment: Because OP specified the order that he wants? @pamu

Comment: @pamu Almost every function in the world of programming depends on the order of input parameters. And you are right it fails for some inputs... I will have to fix that.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh got it

Answer (score 0):

Got something that should yield some improvements and is more idiomatic.

```
  def check(s: String, obj: String): Boolean = {
    if(s.length == obj.length + 1)
      streamFromString(s, 0).exists { case(substring) => substring == obj }
    else false
  }

  def streamFromString(s: String, withoutIndex: Int): Stream[String] = {
    lazy val next: Stream[String] = if(withoutIndex > s.length - 1) Stream.empty else streamFromString(s, withoutIndex + 1)
    s.patch(withoutIndex, Nil, 1) #:: next
  }
```

First of all, you could use `patch` to create subcollections without the given element; it's defined on `Seq` so feel free to read up on that.

Secondly, instead of looping mindlessly and reinventing the wheel I decided to create a `Stream[String]` of the created patches but since `Stream` is a lazy collection we will create subsequent patches only as we progress through the stream.

You could replace the `exists` call with `collectFirst` that takes a `PartialFunction` for more control over the body but it would be an overkill in this case, imo.

```
  streamFromString(s, 0)
    .collectFirst { case (substring) if substring == obj => "" } //could be anything here really, it's all about getting Option.Some
    .fold(false)(_ => true)
```

Comment: Scala streams are not always good for performance considering the overhead. And this is one of those cases.